# Player Turn Based Card Game

Tags: java

Currently I have one simple program with 2 player and they can play some calculation card game. 
The player turn function currently I using is

```
int turn=0;
    while(!gameCheck(p1,p2)) {
        if(turn%2==0) {
        plyGame(p1);}
        else {
        plyGame(p2);}
        turn++;
```

if lets say I want to let player become 4 player , the code become like this:

```
 int turn=1;
    while(!gameCheck(p1,p2,p3,p4)) {
        if(turn%4==1) {
        plyGame(p1);}
        else if(turn%4==2){
        plyGame(p2);}
        else if(turn%4==3){
        plyGame(p3);}
        else {
        plyGame(p4);}
        turn++;
```

If I add special effect like reverse the order of player, what method should I do in order to reverse the player order (if currently is a turn of player 3, a random event occur to reverse the order, next player become player 2, then player 1 and then back to player 4)?

Comment: Don't hardcode the number of players, use a collection (eg an array, or maybe an `ArrayList`) and select the player by index. This will simplify your code, and simplify most of your problems to manipulations of index of the current player in a range of [0, playerCount), etc.

Comment: A circular doubly linked list might help you. Based on the event you can either move forward or back

Comment: You can create a set_turn function that takes as a parameter a player and re-initializes the turn for this player. But it is not very clear what you want to achieve ... what is the gameCheck function does ?

Comment: @AndrewZacharakis the gameCheck function is a function that display the msg in the game is over and display the winner. Inside has function to check either player reach win condition or not.

Comment: Ok, so having just a variable for the turn is not such a good design. Working on a similar project a few months back, i suggest you create a class named turn. The constructor can initialize the turn of the player who plays first (randomly or by choice) and the a set_turn function can set the new player's turn. However do not use int ...instead use an object of type player (another class named player)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to study and implement [state design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state) for this situation.

The state pattern is a behavioral software design pattern that implements a state machine in an object-oriented way. With the state pattern, a state machine is implemented by implementing each individual state as a derived class of the state pattern interface, and implementing state transitions by invoking methods defined by the pattern's superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Put your players in an array, then you can do `plyGame(players[turn % players.length])` and if you want to change the order you can either move the players in the `players` array or do stuff like `plyGame(players[players.length - 1 - turn % players.length])`.

Else you could have your players in a list and you would implement a variant of the ListIterator that is cyclic (go back to index 0 after last index, and to last index after index 0 if you go in reverse) and use next() and previous() to get the current player each turn.

Comment: The last statement I tried. It work for first round but not second rotation, 
for example I have 3 player A,B,C. C activate the random reverse event, turn goes back to B later and goes back to A, after that A the turn will go back to B but I want it go back to C. It sound like a clockwise turn into anti-clockwise

Comment: Yeah, I though you might need that, that's why I said that moving the players inside the array might be a solution, like if C activate the reverse event, you move current player to index 0 then you take put the player that played before him (turn-1) and you put it in index 1, then you take the player that played before him (turn-2) and you put it in index 2 (and you continue if there is more players).

Comment: Also added a version using a ListIterator, which is probably more complex to understand if you have little knowledge of Java but is more easy to use once implemented.